# Angular 5 with require throwing Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Tags: angular, webpack, angular5, require

I have an Angular 5 application that I am trying to use require in. I have the following as my app.component.ts file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: require('./app.component.html')
})

export class AppComponent {

}
```

And an app.component.html file:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="main-content">
        <!-- Acts as a placeholder that Angular dynamically fills content based on the current router state. -->
        <router-outlet>
        </router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

The router for testing just routes to an empty component that references a Hello World HTML file. When I run this using require, I get the following error:

```
zone.js?fad3:672 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

at MatCommonModule._checkThemeIsPresent (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:544), <anonymous>:148:33)
at new MatCommonModule (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:544), <anonymous>:100:18)
at _createClass (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:11), <anonymous>:10661:20)
at _createProviderInstance$1 (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:11), <anonymous>:10635:26)
at initNgModule (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:11), <anonymous>:10588:28)
at new NgModuleRef_ (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:11), <anonymous>:11831:9)
at createNgModuleRef (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:11), <anonymous>:11821:12)
at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:11), <anonymous>:14131:12)
at NgModuleFactory_.create (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:11), <anonymous>:15255:25)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:11), <anonymous>:5409:78)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (polyfills.js:2027), <anonymous>:388:26)
at Object.onInvoke (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:11), <anonymous>:4668:33)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (polyfills.js:2027), <anonymous>:387:32)
at Zone.run (eval at <anonymous> (polyfills.js:2027), <anonymous>:138:43)
at NgZone.run (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:11), <anonymous>:4485:69)
at PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:11), <anonymous>:5407:23)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.js:11), <anonymous>:5486:59)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (polyfills.js:2027), <anonymous>:388:26)
at Zone.run (eval at <anonymous> (polyfills.js:2027), <anonymous>:138:43)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (polyfills.js:2027), <anonymous>:858:57)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (polyfills.js:2027), <anonymous>:421:31)
at Zone.runTask (eval at <anonymous> (polyfills.js:2027), <anonymous>:188:47)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (eval at <anonymous> (polyfills.js:2027), <anonymous>:595:35) TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
at MatCommonModule._checkThemeIsPresent (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/vendor.js:544:2), <anonymous>:148:33)
at new MatCommonModule (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/vendor.js:544:2), <anonymous>:100:18)
at _createClass (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/vendor.js:11:2), <anonymous>:10661:20)
at _createProviderInstance$1 (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/vendor.js:11:2), <anonymous>:10635:26)
at initNgModule (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/vendor.js:11:2), <anonymous>:10588:28)
at new NgModuleRef_ (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/vendor.js:11:2), <anonymous>:11831:9)
at createNgModuleRef (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/vendor.js:11:2), <anonymous>:11821:12)
at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/vendor.js:11:2), <anonymous>:14131:12)
at NgModuleFactory_.create (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/vendor.js:11:2), <anonymous>:15255:25)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/vendor.js:11:2), <anonymous>:5409:78)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/polyfills.js:2027:2), <anonymous>:388:26)
at Object.onInvoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/vendor.js:11:2), <anonymous>:4668:33)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/polyfills.js:2027:2), <anonymous>:387:32)
at Zone.run (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/polyfills.js:2027:2), <anonymous>:138:43)
at NgZone.run (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/vendor.js:11:2), <anonymous>:4485:69)
at PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/vendor.js:11:2), <anonymous>:5407:23)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/vendor.js:11:2), <anonymous>:5486:59)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/polyfills.js:2027:2), <anonymous>:388:26)
at Zone.run (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/polyfills.js:2027:2), <anonymous>:138:43)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/polyfills.js:2027:2), <anonymous>:858:57)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/polyfills.js:2027:2), <anonymous>:421:31)
at Zone.runTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/polyfills.js:2027:2), <anonymous>:188:47)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (eval at <anonymous> (http://mderrybe.aka.corp.amazon.com:6789/polyfills.js:2027:2), <anonymous>:595:35)
```

Interestingly enough, I do NOT get this error if I do not use require and instead just reference the file using templateUrl, like this:

```
templateUrl: 'src/app/app.component.html'
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? Why does require cause this error? Thank you!

Comment: Why you using `require()`? `template` is used for inline HTML.

Comment: I just tried your code in angular 6 and I don't have any problem. You are in production mode perhaps ?  with require it give me back the "html" template so yes we can use it with template

Comment: If you  just after all import statement you add "const tmp = require(...);   and console.log(tmp);     does it display your template ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should write your app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

and your app.component.html:

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

So, you error sould be here:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: require('./app.component.html')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#template) `template` is used for inline HTML. So, you should provide inline HTML as string if you want to use `template` property.

On the other side if you want to use path to HTML file you should use `templateUrl` property. Please read about [templateUrl](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#templateUrl) in Angular docs.

Function `require()` is not good fit here because it is node function used to load modules. Please check [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require).